# I have a string with link-text + link-adress, how do I present it in UIWebView?

Tags: html, objective-c, parsing, hyperlink

When I parse a description of a news from the rss, there is a link in this format:

> Little invention of the 4 april 2012 (index.php?option=com_content task=view id=157 Itemid=100).

I want to present a hyperlink with link-text:

> Little invention of the 4 april 2012

and link-adress:

> index.php?option=com_content task=view id=157 Itemid=100

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain needed strings like this:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:@"Little invention of the 4 april 2012 (index.php?option=com_content task=view id=157 Itemid=100)"];
int linkStartIndex = [string rangeOfString:@"(" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location;
NSString *name = [string substringToIndex:linkStartIndex];
NSString *adress = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(linkStartIndex+1, string.length-linkStartIndex-2)];
NSLog(@"\nname = [%@], \naddress = [%@]", name, adress);
```

Than if you use UIWebView to present it, add to the html of your webView this string:

```
NSString *linkTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"%@\">%@</a>", adress, name];
```

Comment: Or, if his pattern is that predictable, just separate it on @" (" and grab the first element of the array.

Comment: Thanks for your help,

I misspoke, I would finally get a pushing link.

If I Have : Little invention of the 4 april 2012 (index.php?option=com_content task=view id=157 Itemid=100), I would optain a link on Little invention of the 4 april without showing the link after this text.

I don't know if what I said is clear, sorry.

Danich sorry but the title is false :-(

Comment: I need the link in the name !

Comment: Thanks, it work fine. I just have to convert "Little invention of the 4 april 2012" for it becomes a link with the address (index.php?option=com_content task=view id=157 Itemid=100). Do you know how to do it ?

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: No no, this is my first question. There is a part of my question for separt the title and the link and the second par now is that i have to optain a link ^^